# Stylistic sets for the STIX (One) Fonts

Tags: fonts, luatex, stix

I have been looking for an overview of the stylistic sets for the STIX OTF fonts, but I have only been able to find the documentation for the "LaTeX" fonts which I presume are the Type 1 fonts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These stylistic sets affect only the roman and bold faces. Compile the following to see their effects: it’s the relevant parts of the feature file (as seen in FontForge) converted into LaTeX tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,fontspec,longtable}
\setmainfont{STIX}
\begin{document}
\centering
\section{Stylistic Set One}
\begin{tabular}{l>{\addfontfeatures{StylisticSet=1}}{l}}
  \symbol{"222B} & \symbol{"222B} \\
  \symbol{"222C} & \symbol{"222C} \\
  \symbol{"222D} & \symbol{"222D} \\
  \symbol{"222E} & \symbol{"222E} \\
  \symbol{"222F} & \symbol{"222F} \\
  \symbol{"2230} & \symbol{"2230} \\
  \symbol{"2231} & \symbol{"2231} \\
  \symbol{"2232} & \symbol{"2232} \\
  \symbol{"2233} & \symbol{"2233} \\
  \symbol{"2A0B} & \symbol{"2A0B} \\
  \symbol{"2A0C} & \symbol{"2A0C} \\
  \symbol{"2A0D} & \symbol{"2A0D} \\
  \symbol{"2A0E} & \symbol{"2A0E} \\
  \symbol{"2A0F} & \symbol{"2A0F} \\
  \symbol{"2A10} & \symbol{"2A10} \\
  \symbol{"2A11} & \symbol{"2A11} \\
  \symbol{"2A12} & \symbol{"2A12} \\
  \symbol{"2A13} & \symbol{"2A13} \\
  \symbol{"2A14} & \symbol{"2A14} \\
  \symbol{"2A15} & \symbol{"2A15} \\
  \symbol{"2A16} & \symbol{"2A16} \\
  \symbol{"2A17} & \symbol{"2A17} \\
  \symbol{"2A18} & \symbol{"2A18} \\
  \symbol{"2A19} & \symbol{"2A19} \\
  \symbol{"2A1A} & \symbol{"2A1A} \\
  \symbol{"2A1B} & \symbol{"2A1B} \\
  \symbol{"2A1C} & \symbol{"2A1C} \\
\end{tabular}

\section{Stylistic Set Two}
\begin{tabular}{l>{\addfontfeatures{StylisticSet=2}}{l}}
  \symbol{"2241} & \symbol{"2241} \\
  \symbol{"2244} & \symbol{"2244} \\
  \symbol{"2247} & \symbol{"2247} \\
  \symbol{"2249} & \symbol{"2249} \\
  \symbol{"2260} & \symbol{"2260} \\
  \symbol{"2262} & \symbol{"2262} \\
  \symbol{"2268} & \symbol{"2268} \\
  \symbol{"2269} & \symbol{"2269} \\
  \symbol{"226D} & \symbol{"226D} \\
  \symbol{"226E} & \symbol{"226E} \\
  \symbol{"226F} & \symbol{"226F} \\
  \symbol{"2270} & \symbol{"2270} \\
  \symbol{"2271} & \symbol{"2271} \\
  \symbol{"2274} & \symbol{"2274} \\
  \symbol{"2275} & \symbol{"2275} \\
  \symbol{"2278} & \symbol{"2278} \\
  \symbol{"2279} & \symbol{"2279} \\
  \symbol{"2280} & \symbol{"2280} \\
  \symbol{"2281} & \symbol{"2281} \\
  \symbol{"2284} & \symbol{"2284} \\
  \symbol{"2285} & \symbol{"2285} \\
  \symbol{"2288} & \symbol{"2288} \\
  \symbol{"2289} & \symbol{"2289} \\
  \symbol{"228A} & \symbol{"228A} \\
  \symbol{"228B} & \symbol{"228B} \\
  \symbol{"22E0} & \symbol{"22E0} \\
  \symbol{"22E1} & \symbol{"22E1} \\
  \symbol{"22EC} & \symbol{"22EC} \\
  \symbol{"22ED} & \symbol{"22ED} \\
\end{tabular}

\section{Stylistic Set Three}
\begin{longtable}{l>{\addfontfeatures{StylisticSet=3}}{l}}
  w              & w              \\
  |              & |              \\
  \symbol{"019B} & \symbol{"019B} \\
  \symbol{"0264} & \symbol{"0264} \\
  \symbol{"2032} & \symbol{"2032} \\
  \symbol{"2033} & \symbol{"2033} \\
  \symbol{"2034} & \symbol{"2034} \\
  \symbol{"2035} & \symbol{"2035} \\
  \symbol{"2036} & \symbol{"2036} \\
  \symbol{"2037} & \symbol{"2037} \\
  \symbol{"2057} & \symbol{"2057} \\
  \symbol{"210F} & \symbol{"210F} \\
  \symbol{"2140} & \symbol{"2140} \\
  \symbol{"2190} & \symbol{"2190} \\
  \symbol{"2191} & \symbol{"2191} \\
  \symbol{"2192} & \symbol{"2192} \\
  \symbol{"2193} & \symbol{"2193} \\
  \symbol{"21D1} & \symbol{"21D1} \\
  \symbol{"21D3} & \symbol{"21D3} \\
  \symbol{"21E0} & \symbol{"21E0} \\
  \symbol{"21E2} & \symbol{"21E2} \\
  \symbol{"2205} & \symbol{"2205} \\
  \symbol{"2208} & \symbol{"2208} \\
  \symbol{"2209} & \symbol{"2209} \\
  \symbol{"220B} & \symbol{"220B} \\
  \symbol{"220C} & \symbol{"220C} \\
  \symbol{"220F} & \symbol{"220F} \\
  \symbol{"2210} & \symbol{"2210} \\
  \symbol{"2211} & \symbol{"2211} \\
  \symbol{"2216} & \symbol{"2216} \\
  \symbol{"221A} & \symbol{"221A} \\
  \symbol{"221B} & \symbol{"221B} \\
  \symbol{"221C} & \symbol{"221C} \\
  \symbol{"221D} & \symbol{"221D} \\
  \symbol{"2223} & \symbol{"2223} \\
  \symbol{"2224} & \symbol{"2224} \\
  \symbol{"2225} & \symbol{"2225} \\
  \symbol{"2226} & \symbol{"2226} \\
  \symbol{"2229} & \symbol{"2229} \\
  \symbol{"222A} & \symbol{"222A} \\
  \symbol{"223C} & \symbol{"223C} \\
  \symbol{"223E} & \symbol{"223E} \\
  \symbol{"223F} & \symbol{"223F} \\
  \symbol{"2248} & \symbol{"2248} \\
  \symbol{"224C} & \symbol{"224C} \\
  \symbol{"2272} & \symbol{"2272} \\
  \symbol{"2273} & \symbol{"2273} \\
  \symbol{"2293} & \symbol{"2293} \\
  \symbol{"2294} & \symbol{"2294} \\
  \symbol{"2295} & \symbol{"2295} \\
  \symbol{"2297} & \symbol{"2297} \\
  \symbol{"229C} & \symbol{"229C} \\
  \symbol{"22DA} & \symbol{"22DA} \\
  \symbol{"22DB} & \symbol{"22DB} \\
  \symbol{"2322} & \symbol{"2322} \\
  \symbol{"2323} & \symbol{"2323} \\
  \symbol{"2423} & \symbol{"2423} \\
  \symbol{"25A9} & \symbol{"25A9} \\
  \symbol{"2A3C} & \symbol{"2A3C} \\
  \symbol{"2A3D} & \symbol{"2A3D} \\
  \symbol{"2A9D} & \symbol{"2A9D} \\
  \symbol{"2A9E} & \symbol{"2A9E} \\
  \symbol{"2AAC} & \symbol{"2AAC} \\
  \symbol{"2AAD} & \symbol{"2AAD} \\
  \symbol{"2ACB} & \symbol{"2ACB} \\
  \symbol{"2ACC} & \symbol{"2ACC} \\
  \symbol{"2AEE} & \symbol{"2AEE} \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

As you’ll see, `ss01` produces upright forms for some mathematical symbols. `ss02` makes the line indicating negation upright in some mathematical symbols. The effects of `ss03` are more varied: it shortens some mathematical symbols, makes other narrower, makes still others bigger, etc.